# Laravel не видит инжектируемый класс

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Доброго времени суток.
Столкнулся со следующей ошибкой:

> Class App\Services\PuzzleService does not exist", "exception":
>   "ReflectionException", "file":
>   "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
>   "line": 811

Контроллер (app/Http/Controllers/PuzzleController.php):

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//Services
use App\Services\PuzzleService;
use App\Services\PlayerService;

//...

class PuzzleController extends Controller
{

    protected $puzzleService;
    protected $playerService;

    public function __construct(PuzzleService $puzzleService, PlayerService $playerService)
    {
        $this->puzzleService = $puzzleService;
        $this->playerService = $playerService;
    }

    //...

}

?>
```

Сам сервис (app\Services\PuzzleService.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

//Services
use App\Services\PlayerService;
use App\Services\RatingService;

//...

class PuzzleService {

    protected $playerService;
    protected $ratingService;

    public function __construct(PlayerService $playerService, RatingService $ratingService)
    {
        $this->playerService = $playerService;
        $this->ratingService = $ratingService;
    }

    //...

}

?>
```

Провайдер (app/Providers/PuzzleServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App\Services\PuzzleService;

class PuzzleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $defer = true;

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('PuzzleService', PuzzleService::class);
    }
}

?>
```

В config/app.php в массиве 'providers' запись App\Providers\PuzzleServiceProvider::class присутствует.

Версия laravel:  5.5.17.
Собственно вопрос: что я делаю не так?

Comment: Глупость конечно, а русских букв ни где не закралось?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего необходимо сделать повторную загрузку всех зависимостей через composer.

Пробуйте так:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

После композера можно еще вызвать оптимизированный загрузчик классов для ускорение работы приложения:

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Попробовал, не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в методе самого класса - пропустил точку с запятой:

```
$statistics['puzzles']['elo'] = $ratingData['new_rating'];
```

Если кто столкнется с такой проблемой - обязательно пройдитесь по коду всего класса.

Comment: Добавте фрагмент кода, где не хватает ";" .

Comment: Я добавил в ответ (в следуюший раз уж пожалуйста сами). Только в вопросе этой строчки нет, хотя в сообщении об ошибке номер строки присутствует.

Comment: В том то и дело, laravel указывает, что не может найти класс и отсылает к 811 строке сервис контейнера, но ошибка была в методе класса сервиса. Спасибо.